# Node.Js error Can not set headers after they are sent to client

Tags: node.js, express

i am beginner in node.js and i noticed that after i execute my request the first time it works but node.js launch an error after it that says:

```
Can not set headers after they are sent to client
```

Here what i have tried

questions service:

```
module.exports={
 create:(data,callback)=>{
  var myArray = new Array();
 /* for(let item of data.players) {
    console.log(item.firstname);
}*/

console.log(data);
data.players.forEach((player) => {
  console.log(player.id);
  console.log(player);
  var playerModel ={
    id : player.id,
    firstname : player.firstname,
    lastname : player.lastname,
    position : player.position,
    price : player.price,
    appearences : player.appearences,
    goals : player.goals,
    assists : player.assists,
    cleansheets : player.cleansheets,
    redcards : player.redcards,
    yellowcards : player.yellowcards,
    image : player.image
  };
  console.log("model"+playerModel.position);
  myArray.push(playerModel);
});
var id;
 
 pool.query(
      'insert into club(userid,email,password,name,price) values(?,?,?,?,?)',
   [
        data.userid,
        data.email,
        data.password,
        data.name,
        data.price
      ],
    
      (error,result) => {
        if(error){
          callback(error);
         
        }
        
        for(var item of myArray){
          pool.query(
            
            'insert into players(id,firstname,lastname,position,price,appearences,goals,assists,cleansheets,redcards,yellowcards,image,clubid) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ( SELECT id from club where id > ? ORDER BY id DESC limit 1  ) )',
             [ 
             item.id,
             item.firstname,
             item.lastname,
             item.position,
             item.price,
             item.appearences,
             item.goals,
             item.assists,
             item.cleansheets,
             item.redcards,
             item.yellowcards,
             item.image,
             0
             ],
            
       
           (error,results,fields)=>{
             if(error){
               callback(error);
             }
             return callback(null,results);
           },
          );
          }
        return callback(null,result.insertId);
      },

      
    );
   
  },
```

Questions Controller:

```
const pool = require("../../config/database");
const{create,
  getQuestionsById,
  getQuestionsByCategory,
  getQuestions,
  getValidAnswer,
  setValide,
  CompareAnswers,
  updateQuestions,
  deleteQuestions
}=require("./questions.service");
module.exports={
  createQuestions:(req,res)=>{
    const body = req.body;
      create(body,(err,results)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({
          success:0,
          message:"database connexion error"
        });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({
        success:1,
        data:results
      });
    });
  },
```

Questions router:

```
const{
  createQuestions,
  getQuestionsById,
  getQuestions,
  getQuestionsByCategory,
  getValidAnswer,
  CompareAnswers,
  setValide,
  updateQuestions,
  deleteQuestions,
  
}=require("./questions.controller");
const router = require("express").Router();

router.post("/addQuestion",createQuestions);

router.get("/:id",getQuestionsById);
router.patch("/updateQuestion",updateQuestions);
router.delete("/",deleteQuestions);
router.get("/",getQuestions);
router.get("/VerifyAnswer/:id",getValidAnswer);
router.post("/getByCategory",getQuestionsByCategory);
router.post("/setValide", setValide);
router.post("/CompareAnswers", CompareAnswers);

module.exports=router;
```

My goal is to stop this error and find a solution for it, What is wrong with my code ? and why i have to run again the server after every execute of the request?? why the request works but it launch this error in the end?

A screen capture that shows the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your question service in line:

```
 (error,results,fields)=>{
             if(error){
               callback(error);
             }
```

you should write
`return callback(error)`
This error generally occurs when your code tries to send 2 or more responses for a request. Let me know if it helps.